# Azure Mobile Engagement

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-engagement

I have followed the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mobile-engagement/mobile-engagement-android-get-started) and tried to implement mobile engagement of Azure. Now I want to send notification the device. I can't find how to do it.
I have tried a lot. And also I tried to create Announcements in the REACH tab but still I did not go any notification. Now I am in the middle of the situation, that neither I know, if my could has some fault or I have not yet sent the notification correctly from the portal.
Please help me.
thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should resume the getting started tutorial from this point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mobile-engagement/mobile-engagement-android-get-started#enable-push-notifications-and-in-app-messaging and make sure you follow the GCM steps as well.

If you are still stuck after that, please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks @Perrot you saved my day. Actually I studied it and followed upto some extent but when I did it after your post, I am successful.

Comment: hey! @Perrot I receive the notification but the title and context text that I gave in the azure mobile engagement portal is not shown here in the status bar. You  got any idea? problem with theme?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the campaign details that you created?

Comment: Not Actually that is with backend guys! and they send the message.

Comment: Please check with them, they might be using announcement text which is displayed after click instead of notification text fields.